# Collection Initializers in C#

Tags: c#, java, static-initializer, static-initialization

In Java, I can create an List and immediately populate it using a static initializer. Something like this:

```
List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>()
{{
    Add("a");
    Add("b");
    Add("c");
}}
```

Which is convenient, because I can create the list on the fly, and pass it as an argument into a function. Something like this:

```
printList(new ArrayList<String>()
{{
    Add("a");
    Add("b");
    Add("c");
}});
```

I am new to C# and trying to figure out how to do this, but am coming up empty. Is this possible in C#? And if so, how can it be done?

Comment: this isn't a "[static initializer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)" - it's an instance initializer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a collection initializer:

```
new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" }
```

This compiles to a sequence of calls to the `Add` method.
If the `Add` method takes multiple arguments (eg, a dictionary), you'll need to wrap each call in a separate pair of braces:

```
new Dictionary<string, Exception> {
    { "a", new InvalidProgramException() },
    { "b", null },
    { "c", new BadImageFormatException() }
}
```

Comment: @user489041 : you can initialize Dictionary as well, see an example in my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Since `C# 3.0` you can do it as well:

```
List <String> list = new List<String>
                     {
                             "a", "b", "c"
                     };
```

MSDN, [Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element
>   intializers when you initialize a collection class that implements
>   IEnumerable. The element initializers can be a simple value, an
>   expression or an object initializer. By using a collection initializer
>   you do not have to specify multiple calls to the Add method of the
>   class in your source code; the compiler adds the calls.

**EDIT:** Answer to comment regarding dictionary

```
IDictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   { "Key0", "Value0" },
   { "Key1", "Value1" }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's described on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)